# Kylo | High Water Mark functionality

Tags: kylo

I have feed running in every five minute and using load/release hive water mark feature. Consider a scenario where job execution took more than 5 minutes and water mark commit did not happen.

In this scenario will Kylo launch another feed instance with old water mark or will it wait for commit to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a watermark is active (i.e. a flowfile loaded the watermark and is processing it, but has not yet released it), a new flowfile attempting to again load the same watermark will be blocked. It will wait for the active watermark to be released (via a commit or reject).

You can exercise control over this behavior via the '**Active Water Mark Strategy**' property on the '**LoadHighWaterMark**' processor. These can help in cases where processing is stuck or is taking longer than expected. If the strategy is set to '**Yield**', the processor will yield if watermark is active. The number of times the yield happens is configured via the processor property '**Max Yield Count**'. Once this yield count is reached, processor will route flowfile to '**ActiveFailure**' relationship. Duration of each yield can be set via *Settings -> Yield Duration* on the processor. If the strategy is set to '**Route**', the processor will immediately route flowfile to '**ActiveFailure**' relationship.

Take care to use the '**ReleaseHighWaterMark**' processor at leaf **Success**, **Failure** and **ActiveFailure** relationships. It supports two modes - **commit** and **reject**.

Answer (score 3):

### **In answer to your specific question:**

If your **LoadHighWaterMark** processor is the first one in your feed’s flow (common case) then, when it wakes again up after 5 minutes while the water mark is active, it will effectively do nothing (after removing any created flowfile) and wait another 5 minutes to be scheduled again.  The processor will yield first but, since the typical yield time is less than 5 minutes, the yield is irrevalent.

If your **LoadHighWaterMark** processor is not the first in the flow, then the flowfile created after the 5 minute wakeup will be re-queued and the processor will either yield or penalize that flowfile depending upon the configuration.  This will happen every time the feed processing takes longer than 5 minutes.

So the answer to your question is ***no***, new processing will not resume with the old water mark but will wait for the current water mark's commit or release without commit.  The two cases above assume a typical configuration regarding response to an active water mark and that your feed is behaving properly but simply took longer than 5 minutes to process a particular batch of data.

Note that if your feed on average takes longer than 5 minutes to process its data then it would be wise to change the feed’s schedule to a value higher than 5 minutes so the processor’s queue does not get backed up.  Again, this is only necessary if the **LoadHighWaterMark** is not the first processor.

### General behaviour:

If a flowfile is currently being processed within the section of your Feed’s NiFi flow bounded by your **LoadHighWaterMark** and **ReleaseHighWaterMark** processors, then no other flowfile may enter that section of the flow until the current processing flowfile exits that section by passing through a **ReleaseHighWaterMark** processor; whether the water mark is committed or not.  This sequence of your flow is treated like a critical section.  This is why every flow path, whether a success path or a failure path, must pass through a **ReleaseHighWaterMark** of some kind.

Now the NiFi flow behavior when a your feed wakes up and attempts to process a new flowfile while the water mark is active is determined by the location of the **LoadHighWaterMark** in your flow and its configuration.  The **Active Water Mark Strategy** setting affects how the processor behaves when a flowfile arrives while the water mark is active:

- **YIELD** - the flow file will be removed (if 1st processor) or re-queued and the processor will yield for its specified yield time
- **PENALIZE** - the flowfile will be penalized; causing it to be re-queued
- **ROUTE** - the flowfile will immediately be routed to the **activeFailure** relationship

Note that **PENALIZE** does not make sense if the the **LoadHighWaterMark** processor is the first processor in the flow (no queue involved.)  So setting the **Active Water Mark Strategy** to **PENALIZE** will be treated as if it were set to **YIELD**.

Another configuration setting affecting behavior is **Max Yield Count**.  This value specifies how many times an attempt to load and process an active water mark should be made before the flowfile is routed to the **activeFailure** relationship.  So in your scenario, if the max count was set to 3, and the current feed processing took more than 20 minutes (5 min. X 4), then all the flowfiles starting with the fourth one would be immediately routed to **activeFailure** until the active water mark processing finished.  At that point the attempt count is reset back to 0 and the next arriving flowfile will begin processing with the new water mark value.

Answer (score 0):

I'll need to confirm this but my understanding is that a new High Water Mark would only run once the current High Water Mark is released. It's important to ensure that all 'success' and 'failure' relationships end with a ReleaseHighWaterMark processor. Otherwise your feed could end up in an inconsistent state where the High Water Mark hasn't been released but a new High Water Mark cannot be loaded.

Comment: thanks for reply. Can you please confirm behavior ? Let me know if it requires JIRA.